# UIImageView, CGImage, and Retina Art

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgimage

I've got a few CALayers in my interface, and I'm drawing images directly to the layers as opposed to imageViews.

Here's a snippet:

```
UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage"];
CGImageRef anImageRef = [anImage CGImage];
CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
CGFloat anImageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(anImageRef);
CGFloat anImageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(anImageRef);
CGRect layerFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,anImageWidth, anImageHeight);
[aLayer setLayerContents:(__bridge id)anImageRef];
[parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];
```

So my *problem* is that I'm getting inconsistent results with the size of the image. On the retina Device, the image that appears is double the size anticipated (e.g., it matches the pixel size of the @2x image). On the simulator in retina mode, the image drawn to the layer is the anticipated size (where points match the pixels of the *non* retina image).

Rather than statically set the size, or halve the size (which corrects the issue on the device but breaks compatibility with non-retina displays), what is a good solution or workaround to this scenario? Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIImage` contains a scale property. It will be 2.0 for retina display images. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: For some reason my brain told me that scale was a property on imageViews, not on images, which is why next time I'll ask docs instead. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

`CGImageGetWidth()` and `CGImageGetHeight()` return the number of *pixels* whereas you need the image size in *points*. Use `-[UIImage size]` instead.